# Where can I find ipseccmd.exe?

Tags: windows, ipsec

Reading this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813878

I have a question: Where can I get ipseccmd.exe for Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article you link to:

> IPSeccmd.exe is part of Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) Support Tools.

A quick search suggests this is the download page:

- [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18546)

Comment: Thanks, but this. Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 32-bit Support Tools: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7911